# Claws mail: Filtering windows problem in Unity?

Tags: 12.04, unity, claws

I have been informed, via the Claws mail users (e-mail) list, that the following issue may be Unity-related.  Comments / ideas / suggestions? Thanks.

---

Original question:

Often when I am editing or creating a Filter in Claws mail and I make a mistake, the Filtering window / dialog windows will not respond to mouse clicks (OK; Cancel).  Hence, there is no way to close these windows.

I can minimize every window, Super-Window to see all windows on that desktop, etc., so a hidden window does not appear to be the issue.  When this issue arises (often), the only way to get rid of these windows is kill Claws mail using the System Monitor, then restart CM.

Suggestions?  Thanks ...

FYI: replies / followups, from the Claws User List (oldest first):

Reply 1 (another CM user).  Stuff like that happens to me on Ubuntu 11.10 Linux all the time. It's especially annoying on the Quick Search search construction window, which if you do it slightly wrong, gives you an error message box with an OK that clicking does nothing to.

Reply 2 (me). This is exactly the behavior I am describing.  It has been an ongoing occurrence / annoyance for some months (probably since some CM update).

Reply 3 (Claws mail development / support team). Do you use Unity? This seems to only occur when using Unity.

Reply 4 (me). Yes, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Unity.

Reply 5 (Claws mail development / support team).  Unity is the problem. Not sure if we can do anything about that, but it doesn't look good.

---

Answer (score 1):

The bug is with overlay-scrollbar breaking modal dialogues.  This is [the relevant bug at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/903302).

One way to fix this is to open Claws Mail without overlay scrollbars.

To do so, you need to add a .desktop file for Claws Mail (claws-mail.desktop), and to create an executable shell file (claws-mail-startup.sh) with "LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0" and use that to open Claws.

To create the shell file:

```
$ mkdir scripts
$ nano scripts/claws-mail-startup.sh
```

Copy the below text, go to terminal, press `Ctrl+Shift+V` (to paste) `Ctrl+O` (to save), and `Ctrl+X` (to exit).  Then:

```
$ chmod +x scripts/claws-mail-startup.sh
```

Content of shell file:

```
#!/bin/sh
LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 claws-mail
```

You need to create claws-mail.desktop in /usr/share/applications/

```
$ sudo nano /usr/share/applications/claws-mail.desktop
```

It should have the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Claws Mail
GenericName=E-mail client
GenericName[ca]=Client de correu electrònic
GenericName[cs]=E-mailový klient
GenericName[da]=E-post klient
GenericName[es]=Cliente de correo electrónico
GenericName[fi]=Sähköpostiohjelma
GenericName[fr]=Client de messagerie électronique
GenericName[hu]=Levelezőkliens
GenericName[id]=Pembaca E-mail
GenericName[ja]=Eメールクライアント
GenericName[lt]=El. pašto klientas
GenericName[pl]=Program poczty elektronicznej
GenericName[pt-br]=Cliente de e-mail
GenericName[sk]=Poštový klient
GenericName[sv]=E-postklient
Exec=claws-mail %u
Icon=claws-mail
Categories=Network;Email;
Keywords=lightweight fast x-window extensible plugin pop3 imap nntp
Comment=Lightweight and Fast GTK+ based Mail Client
Comment[ca]=Client de correu electrònic ràpid i lleuger basat en GTK+
Comment[cs]=Lehký a rychlý mailový klient založený na GTK+
Comment[da]=Letvægts og hurtig GTK+ baseret e-post klient
Comment[es]=Cliente de correo rápido y ligero basado en GTK+
Comment[fi]=Kevyt ja nopea GTK+-pohjainen sähköpostiohjelma
Comment[fr]=Client de messagerie électronique, rapide et léger, en GTK+
Comment[hu]=Pehelysúlyú és gyors GTK+ alapú levelezőkliens
Comment[id]=Pembaca e-mail berbasis GTK+ yang cepat dan ringan
Comment[ja]=軽量で早いGTK+ベースのEメールクライアント
Comment[lt]=Lengvas ir greitas el. pašto klientas GTK+ pagrindu
Comment[pl]=Program pocztowy używający GTK+
Comment[pt-br]=Cliente de e-mail leve e rápido, baseado em GTK+
Comment[sk]=Odľahčený a rýchly poštový klient, založený na GTK+
Comment[sv]=Lättviktig och snabb GTK+-baserad E-postklient
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;
X-Info=Claws Mail
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: One way to fix this is to add a .desktop file for Claws Mail (ClawsMail.desktop), and to create an executable shell file (ClawsMailStartup.sh) and use that to open Claws.